# Broken navigation in android app

Tags: bug, android-app

Go to Achievements and click on a badge row (not the icon).
End up on an empty page which says "The mapper function returned a null value"

[image: screenshot]               [image: screenshot]

App version: 1.0.4, Android version: 7.0